# drupal module configuration process uploaded file

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How can I process a file upload in a module configuration section? Here is what I have so far.

```
<?php
function dc_staff_directory_admin_settings() 
{
  $form['dc_staff_directory_upload_file'] = array(
    '#type' => 'file',
    '#title' => t('Upload staff directory excel (.xls) file'),
    '#description' => t('Uploading a file will replace the current staff directory'),
  );
  $form['#submit'][] = 'dc_staff_directory_process_uploaded_file';
  return system_settings_form($form);
}

function dc_staff_directory_process_uploaded_file($form, &$form_state)
{
   //What can I do here to get the file data?
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the `managed_file` type instead Drupal will do most of the processing for you, you just need to mark the file for permanent storage in your submit function:

```
function dc_staff_directory_admin_settings() {
  $form['dc_staff_directory_upload_file'] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#title' => t('Upload staff directory excel (.xls) file'),
    '#description' => t('Uploading a file will replace the current staff directory'),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://path/'
  );

  $form['#submit'][] = 'dc_staff_directory_process_uploaded_file';
  $form['#validate'][] = 'dc_staff_directory_validate_uploaded_file';
  return system_settings_form($form);
}

function db_staff_directory_validate_uploaded_file($form, &$form_state) {
  if (!isset($form_state['values']['dc_staff_directory_upload_file']) || !is_numeric($form_state['values']['dc_staff_directory_upload_file'])) {
    form_set_error('dc_staff_directory_upload_file', t('Please select an file to upload.'));
  }
}

function dc_staff_directory_process_uploaded_file($form, &$form_state) {
   if ($form_state['values']['dc_staff_directory_upload_file'] != 0) {
      // The new file's status is set to 0 or temporary and in order to ensure
      // that the file is not removed after 6 hours we need to change it's status
      // to 1.
      $file = file_load($form_state['values']['dc_staff_directory_upload_file']);
      $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
      file_save($file);
   }

}
```

The validate function is probably a good idea as well, obviously you won't need it if the file is not a required field.

This is mostly taken from the `image_example` module, part of the [Examples Module](http://drupal.org/project/examples). If you really don't want to use the `managed_file` type have a look at the `file_example` module in that same collection, it has examples of how to uploaded an unmanaged file.

Hope that helps